# Unable to determine the principle end of the relationship - multiple added entities may have the same primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, ef-code-first

Sets have Cards and Sets.  Here's what I have in my model, using EF Code First:

```
public class Set
{
    // Primitive Properties 
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public virtual int SetId { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties 
    [Required]
    public virtual List<Set> Sets { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    [ForeignKey("ParentSet")]
    public int ParentSetId { get; set; }
    public virtual Set ParentSet { get; set; }
}
```

Then for Cards:

```
public class Card
{
    // Primitive Properties
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public virtual int CardId { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ParentSet")]
    public int ParentSetId { get; set; }
    public virtual Set ParentSet { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to rebuild the database using 'update-database' from the package manager console and this is the error I'm getting:

> Unable to determine the principal end of the
>   'App.Core.Set_ParentSet' relationship. Multiple added entities
>   may have the same primary key.

Any idea why?

Comment: I don't get the relationships within the Set table.  What would a uml model look like?  And why would a set need a list of itself?

Comment: Sets would be self-referencing... since a Set can have many Sets.  Like a Box can have many Boxes and may belong to a Box.  Is this allowed?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I don't know how EF would reconcile that relationship.  I would consider defining ParentSets and/or SubSets separately from the PrimarySet.

Comment: Although, I can see how much fun it would be to read code like `foreach(Set set in Set.Sets)`

Comment: I hate to downvote the question, but @RobVious seems to have marked an answer as The Answer when, according to his comments, it does not solve the problem.  Please unmark that answer as The Answer or explain how it fixed the problem.  I really wish there were any solutions that worked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me having this in the Set entity doesn't make sense. It can't refer to itself and be required

```
// Navigation Properties 
[Required]
public virtual List<Set> Sets { get; set; }
```

If a `Set` HAS to have a list of `Sets`, how can you create the first  `Set`?

Note that from what's written in the error, it has nothing to do with the Card class

Comment: Thanks for the help Mathieu.  I'm trying to make sure the List<> is instantiated so I don't have to do checks for isNull before doing stuff like Sets.Count.  The List should always be there but won't always have Sets in it.  Thoughts?

Comment: I tried relationships inside the same entity before. It doesn't work. You'd be better off having a property 'public virtual int? ParentSetId { get; set; }'

Comment: I removed the Required and it's still happening.  Note that this wasn't happening before I specified a ForeignKey attribute... should I just leave it off and carry on?

Comment: I don't understand why this was marked as the answer.  @RobVious clearly said it didn't solve the problem, right?  I'm looking for the solution to the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to avoid the null errors from having a newly instantiated `Set` with no `Sets`, then the proper way to handle this is to instantiate `Sets` in the constructor:

```
public class Set
{
    public Set()
    {
        Sets = new List<Set>();
    }

    ...
}
```